# Histogram of occurrences from different datafiles

Tags: shell, awk, gnuplot

The results of my program simulations are several datafiles with the first column indicate success (`=0`) or error (`=1`) and the second column is the simulation time in seconds.

An example of these two columns is:

```
1 185.48736852299064
1 199.44533672989186
1 207.35654106612733
1 213.5214031236177 
1 215.50576147950017
0 219.62444310777695
0 222.26750248416354
0 236.1402270910635 
1 238.5124609287994 
0 246.4538392581228 
.   .
.   .
.   .
1 307.482605596962
1 329.16494123373445
0 329.6454558227778 
1 330.52804695995303
0 332.0673690346546 
0 358.3001385706268 
0 359.82271742496414
1 400.8162129871805 
0 404.88783391725985
1 411.27012219170393
```

I can make a frequency plot (histogram) of the errors (`1's`) binning the data.

```
set encoding iso_8859_1
set key left top 
set ylabel "P_{error}" 
set xlabel "Time [s]" 
set size 1.4, 1.2
set terminal postscript eps enhanced color "Helvetica" 16 
set grid ytics
set key spacing 1.5
set style fill transparent solid 0.3

`grep '^ 1' lookup-ratio-50-0.0034-50-7-20-10-3-1.txt | awk '{print $2}' > t7.dat`

stats 't7.dat' u 1
set output "t7.eps"
binwidth=2000
bin(x,width)=width*floor(x/width)
plot 't7.dat' using (bin($1,binwidth)):(1.0/STATS_records) smooth freq with boxes lc rgb "midnight-blue" title "7x7_P_error"
```

The result

[image]

I want to improve the Gnuplot above to and include the rest of datafiles `lookup-.....-.txt` and their error samples, and join them in the same frequency plot.

I would like also avoiding the use of intermediate files like `t7.dat`.

Besides, I would like to plot a horizontal line of the mean of the error probability.

How could I plot all the sample data in the same plot?

Regards

Comment: simple improvement; remove `grep` and use `awk '$1==1{print $2}'  lookup-*.txt` will extract from matching filenames.  I think you can pipe the output directly to to gnuplot but you're using it in multiple places.

Comment: @karakfa Thank you. It joins all the 2nd columns in one. May I ask you how to pass the output of the `awk` to `stats` and `plot` commands?. This way I would not need to use an intermediate file.

Comment: can't post long code here, look at the answer post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to do the histogram over several files. So, you basically have to concatenate several datafiles. 
Of course, you can do this with some external programs like awk, etc. or shell commands.
Below is a possible solution for gnuplot and a system command and no need for a temporary file. The system command is for Windows, but you probably can easily translate this to Linux. And maybe you need to check whether the "NaN" values do not messup your binning and histogram results.

```
### start code
reset session
# create some dummy data files
do for [i=1:5] {
    set table sprintf("lookup-blahblah_%d.txt", i)
    set samples 50
    plot '+' u (int(rand(0)+0.5)):(rand(0)*0.9+0.1) w table
    unset table
}
# end creating dummy data files

FILELIST = system("dir /B lookup*.txt")   # this is for Windows
print FILELIST

undefine $AllDataWithError
set table $AllDataWithError append
do for [i=1:words(FILELIST)] {
    plot word(FILELIST,i) u ($1==1? $1 : NaN):($1==1? $2 : NaN) w table
}
unset table

print $AllDataWithError

# ... do your binning and plotting
### end of code
```

Edit:

Apparently, `NaN` and/or empty lines seem to mess up `smooth freq` and/or binning?!
So, we need to extract only the lines with errors (=1).
From the above code you can merge several files into one datablock.
The code below already starts with one datablock similar to your data.

```
### start of code
reset session

# create some dummy datablock with some distribution (with no negative values)
Height =3000
Pos = 6000
set table $Data
    set samples 1000
    plot '+' u (int(rand(0)+0.3)):(abs(invnorm(rand(0))*Height+Pos)) w table
unset table
# end creating dummy data

stats $Data nooutput
Datapoints = STATS_records

# get only the error lines
# plot $Data into the table $Dummy.
# If $1==1 (=Error) write the line number $0 into column 1 and value into column 2
# else write NaN into column 1 and column 2.
# Since $0 is the line number which is unique 
# 'smooth frequency' will keep these lines "as is"
# but change the NaN lines to empty lines.
Error = 1
Success = 0
set table $Dummy
    plot $Data u ($1==Error ? $0 : NaN):($1==Error ? $2 : NaN) smooth freq
unset table
# get rid of empty lines in $Dummy
# Since empty lines seem to also mess up binning you need to remove them
# by writing $Dummy into the dataset $Error via "plot ... with table".
set table $Error
   plot $Dummy u 1:2 with table
unset table

bin(x) = binwidth*floor(x/binwidth)
stats $Error nooutput
ErrorCount = STATS_records

set multiplot layout 3,1
set key outside
set label 1 sprintf("Datapoints: %g\nSuccess: %g\nError: %g",\
    Datapoints, Datapoints-ErrorCount,ErrorCount) at graph 1.02, first 0
plot $Data u 0:($1 == Success ? $2 : NaN) w impulses lc rgb "web-green" t "Success",\
    $Data u 0:($1 == Error ? -$2 : NaN) w impulses lc rgb "red" t "Error",\

unset label 1
set key inside
binwidth = 1000
plot $Error using (bin($2)):(1.0/STATS_records) smooth freq with boxes t sprintf("binwidth: %d",binwidth) lc rgb "blue"

binwidth=100
set xrange[GPVAL_X_MIN:GPVAL_X_MAX] # use same xrange as graph before
plot $Error using (bin($2)):(1.0/STATS_records) smooth freq with boxes t sprintf("binwidth: %d",binwidth) lc rgb "magenta"

unset multiplot
### end of code
```

which results in something like:
[image]

Comment: thank you. This is what I intended to do. I also would like to plot the mean error so I should count the errors of the compound file and divide by the count of the data records (errors and success samples). Do you know any way to compute it and add it to the histogram plot?

Comment: also in my plot, to make the binning I use the count of all the error samples (`STAT_records` variable). I assume I could use `$AllDataWithError` in the `stats` command.

Comment: Your code works fine with stats command. The problem with the mean value of errors that I have mentioned and its plot in the histogram is that it seems to vary with the width of the histogram bin. I must compute the probability of error with the samples inside each of the bins and calculate the mean value, but I do not know how to make this computation.

Comment: actually, you can use `stats $AllDataWithError` and then `STATS_records` is the number of the Error (=1) entries and `STATS_invalid` is the number of the success (=0, or now NaN) entries. Might be different if you have some comment lines or empty lines, I haven't checked.

Comment: I apologize but when making my binning and plot commands, `binwidth=1000`
`bin(x,width)=width*floor(x/width)`

`plot $AllDataWithError using (bin($1,binwidth)):(1.0/STATS_records) smooth freq with boxes` it gives an error in the final plot command. Can I use `$AllDatawithError` in the last plot?.

Comment: The plot command I am using is: `plot $AllDataWithError using (bin($1==1? $2,binwidth)):(1.0/STATS_records) smooth freq with boxes` but the eps figure of the plot has zero bytes. Is it possible that NaN records produce this problem? If this the problem how could I take out of the data in the plot?

Comment: My .txt datafiles has also real numbers in the second column if the first column is zero.

Comment: about your zero byte .eps, I guess it's not closed. Add a `set output` at the end of the code. see `help set output`. "If the filename is omitted, any output file opened by a previous invocation of set output will be closed and new output will be sent to STDOUT."

Comment: it plots the eps file but the figure is a wrong histogram. The figure I get is in https://www.dropbox.com/s/v3d0jdmiiyqg40o/t7.eps?dl=0 .

Comment: apparently `NaN` and/or empty lines seem to mess up `smooth freq` and/or binning?! I modified the answer.

Comment: The code of your solution is beautiful. If I understand, `$table` has a column with real positive numbers, or has the first column with 0's and 1's and a real number, like in my data file?. In `$Dummy` you say it takes only the errors. What is `$0`?. I would like to understand better your code. Also, I have tested the code, and it only generates the second and third figures of the multiplot.  Thank you for your solution.

Comment: I have also added `Success = 0` to your code because at first run it only plots me the two last figures of the multiplot. I figure out that it is correct.

Comment: thanks! well, the code is a workaround. Right, sorry, the `Success=0` got somehow lost. `$0` is a pseudcolumn which contains the line number (check `help pseudocolumns`). I'll add more comments to the answer.

Comment: Yes, I meant the code was much-improved :-). I have noticed that the third plot in the multiplot (bin=100) has boxes of different widths. Do you know why?.

Comment: Yes, I also noticed.So far, no idea. Maybe also pixel resolution if the boxes get only a few pixels narrow? It seems to get better if I make the size of the wxt terminal bigger. I still don't fully understand this type of plot.

Answer (score 0):

you can pipe the data and plot directives to gnuplot without a temp file,

for example

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{print "plot \"-\" using ($1):($2)"; 
             while(i++<20) print i,rand()*20; print "e"}' | gnuplot -p
```

will create a random plot.  You can print the directive in the `BEGIN` block as I did and the main `awk` statement can filter the data.

For your plot, something like this

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{print "...." }
       $1==1{print $2}
       END  {print "e"}' lookup-*.txt | gnuplot -p
```

Comment: Thank you. I have tried this awk code, and it gives an error when I use the pipe `gnuplot -p`. I also do not know how to get the mean error probability of all the bin heights.  A horizontal line can be plotted with `set arrow from graph 0, first 0.12 to graph 1, first 0.12 nohead lc rgb "#000000" front` if 0.12 were that mean frequency value but I do not know which value is.

Comment: you have to fill the directives `.....` in `print "...."` Perhaps also missing the last `e` I just added.

Comment: I see that you propose to use the shell to make the plot, but I need the rest of Gnuplot customizations for my figure.